# New mongoDB PHP driver: Query for Distinct records with Limit and Skip and multipal OR condition

Tags: php, mongodb

My code:

```
<?php
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$regex1 = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^jane@mickeyhomes.com","i");

$nameCondition = [];
$nameCondition[] = array('listingParticipants.firstName' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^Mike", 'i'));
$nameCondition[] = array('listingParticipants.lastName' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^Mike", 'i'));

$pipeline = [
    [ '$match' => ['listingParticipants.email' => $regex1] ],
    [ '$group' => ['_id' => '$listingParticipants.email'] ],
    [ '$limit' => 10 ],
    [ '$skip' => 0 ],
];

$aggregate = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
   'aggregate' => 'Listings', 
   'pipeline' => $pipeline,
   'cursor' => new stdClass
]);

$cursor = $mongo->executeCommand('offyApp', $aggregate);

foreach($cursor as $key => $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
?>
```

The above code worked fine and return limit and skip records but i want multiple `OR` condition in this same command my `OR` condition mention in `$nameCondition` in this veritable. So please tell me appropriate answer in above situation.

Summary:

I want a query which will contain limit,skip, or and distinct.

A solution with `executeCommand()` or with `executeQuery()` or anything else will work for me.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the `or` condition inside the `$match` stage like this [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#perform-a-count)

Comment: thanks now its working